# How do I know which version of Tkinter im using?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I want to know which version of Tkintr my Python 2.7 is running...

Thanks for the support :)

I have already done:

```
import Tkinter
Tkinter.TclVersion
```

but it is not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the program throw an error? If so, what's the error? If not, what is it doing differently than you expect?

Answer (score 8):

The module variable `TkVersion` will return a floating point number representing the version of the underlying tk library.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
the_version = tk.TkVersion
```

Comment: For Python 3.8.1 (3.x?) tkinter must be all lower case

Comment: For newer version of Python: `tkinter.TclVersion` will do the job.